# How do you get text to stay when changing scenes

Tags: unity-game-engine

The score for my game is just being displayed through text. Im just using application.loadlevel to change scenes. Don't destroy on load does not work because it destroys the canvas. Any help? Using c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a root object, which is attached the code `DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject)` in the `Awake`. The canvas, which is the child object, will stay all the time.

As for change scene, I would use the following:

```
SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
```

So you can add new scene to the root scene.

Comment: Thanks ill give it a try and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Also how do you create a root scene? Is there anything different involved. Also do you mean to attach the DontDestroyOnLoad onto the scene? If so how could that be done.

Comment: A parent game object called "root", attach the code "DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject)" in "Awake()". Make the canvas be the child game object.

Comment: Why don't you use a Game Manager script, I think it would be best. If it sounds like a good idea to you I can show you a basic Game Manager.

Comment: Daniel Ben-Shabtay, would you be able to assist me further with an example. Thanks.